# Javascript Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': error redrawing screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have the following HTML using jQuery and jQueryUI:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myGrid').widgetGrid();
    });
</script>
```

And then I have the following Jquery widget code (Javascript):

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("mzui.widgetGrid", {
        options: {
        },

        _init: function () {

            this.value = 1;
            this.redraw();
        },


        redraw: function () {
            that = this;
            this.element.empty();

            this.div = $("<div></div>");
            this.element.append(this.div);

            this.text = $("<p>Value = " + this.value.toString() + "</p>");
            this.div.append(this.text);

            this.input = $("<input type='number' onchange='that.onInputChange(value)' min='1' max='100' value='1'/></span>");
            this.div.append(this.input);

        },

        onInputChange: function (value) {

            this.value = value;
            this.redraw();
        },

        _destroy: function () {
            this.element.empty();
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Everything runs fine except that every time I type a new number I´m getting the following error at the browser console:

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is no longer a child of this node. Perhaps it was moved in a 'blur' event handler?
```

This error happens inside the `redraw()` function and does not affect the screen elements at all.

I need help to understand what type of error is what and how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue on fiddle and provide us the link to it ?

Comment: What is `this` here..? is it an html element? does it have a property called `div`…?

Comment: Putting your code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FTFed/ I'm not getting any console errors in firefox or internet explorer (ie!!); you might want to include more details about versions/how you run this/what line throws the error.

Comment: this means the current object. The code is a jquery widget. About the fiddle, it really does no gives me an error in JsFiddle, but if you copy it to a file and run on brownser, it will show you the error (try Chrome ie).